# android read contacts details using ContactsContract

Tags: android

i am querying contacts through

```
private Cursor cursor;
private static final String SORT_ORDER = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ";

String[]   myProjection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, 
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, 
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED};

cursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, myProjection, null, null, SORT_ORDER);
```

and its giving me all contacts details.But my issue is with the duplicate contact details.
Like i am getting a few contacts details multiple times. i think one is from my phone contact another is from facebook contact and from other sites as well.How can i show only one contact of same person in my details.

i have read in some blogs stating a different projection like

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID
```

and different URI

```
RawContacts.CONTENT_URI
```

Can anyone suggest me what is the diff between the two URI.i need to query id,name,photo,phone number,email,starred.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the difference you can follow this page:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html

In nutshell:
A contact (identified by CONTACT_ID) is a virtual, combined contact.  This is what the 2.0 Contacts app shows, where you might have information pulled from two different Google accounts /and/ your Facebook account.
A given contact contains one or more 'raw contacts' (identified by RAW_CONTACT_ID), which are the actual individual records from the different accounts.

Hope this clears your confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.But how can i query it and merge the results to a single contact for a particular CONTACT_ID ?